# Getting "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException" error while trying to use 'protoc-1.0M4.jar'

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I want to generate a protobuf mechanism for use in small embedded application.

I downloaded 'protoc-1.0M4.jar' from protobuf website, and trying to compile using java, my 'test.proto' file to generate C code. Here is the command I used and error I got:

**Command :**

```
$ java -jar protoc-1.0M4.jar test.proto
```

**Exception :**

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58) 
    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
            at edu.tum.cs.ccts.protobuf.embedded.EmbeddedCGenerator.getMaximumSerializedSize(EmbeddedCGenerator.java:491)
            at edu.tum.cs.ccts.protobuf.embedded.EmbeddedCGenerator.compileHeader(EmbeddedCGenerator.java:307)
            at edu.tum.cs.ccts.protobuf.embedded.EmbeddedCGenerator.doGenerate(EmbeddedCGenerator.java:113)
            at edu.tum.cs.ccts.protobuf.embedded.Protoc.main(Protoc.java:126)
            ... 5 more
```

Can anyone suggest some guidelines please.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
is your actual exception. Something is coming as NULL, which should ideally come as an Integer

Comment: Thanks Hirak, but I am using downloaded 'protoc-1.0M4.jar' file. I am much unaware about changing or debugging it.

Comment: can you post your test.proto?

Comment: Hi, Got error removed after adding 3 annotations to my 'test.proto' file. namely "@max_repeated_length/@max_string_length/@max_bytes_length". Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following example code provided in the website and it worked.

```
//File: phone.proto
//
//Optional Embedded C internal options:
//@max_repeated_length=100
//@max_string_length=32
enum PhoneType {  
MOBILE = 0;  
HOME = 1;  
WORK = 2;
}

message PhoneNumber {
 required string number = 1;  
 required PhoneType type = 2;
}
```

I can try running, if you can provide your test.proto